# Dependent lists no ajax

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I'm using [select2](https://select2.github.io/) v4 and trying to make dependent lists with local (already loaded) choices.

```js
var list1 = [
    {id: 42, name: 'xxx'},
    {id: 43, name: 'yyy'}
];

var list2 = [
    {id: 1, name: 'aaa', list1: 42},
    {id: 2, name: 'bbb', list1: 42},
    {id: 3, name: 'ccc', list1: 43},
    {id: 4, name: 'ddd', list1: 43}
]
```

I'd like `list2` to depend on `list1`

I tried to use a callback on `data`:

```js
$('#list1').select2({
    data: list1
});

$('#list2').select2({
    data: function () {
        var list2_filtered = $.grep(list2, function (choice) {
            return choice.list1 == $('#list1').val();
        });
        return list2_filtered;
    }
});
```

but it does not seem to be called.

Why is my callback function never called ?
How can I make these local lists dependent ?

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing a select2 data is a quite known [issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830).

So I implemented my own "data updater":

```js
function refreshSelect($input, data) {
    $input.html($('<option />')); // if a default blank is needed
    for (var key in data) {
        var $option = $('<option />')
            .prop('value', data[key]['id'])
            .text(data[key]['text'])
        ;
        $input.append($option)
    }
    $input.trigger('change');
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```html
<select id="my_select_input"></select>
```

```js
var $input = $('#my_select_input');

var data = [
    {
        id: 42,
        text: 'XX'
    },
    {
        id: 43,
        text: 'YY'
    }
];

refreshSelect($input, data);
```

It works with and without select2